# Installation of ubuntu desktop failing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have a 64 bit PC with the following specifications: i5 10400F B560M pro-vdh 16gb ram I have windows 11 installed and I want to dual boot ubuntu desktop, but I can't get it to work. When installing from an usb drive I've set up with rufus, installation freezes on the "Updates and other software" section. I'm trying to install Ubuntu 21.10. I already tried to add acpi = off at the startup options, but it's still not working. I have ~70gb on my SSD that is deallocated. What else can I try? I opened gparted and it shows errors with a lot of partitions, which I think are recovery partitions from windows, so I think it may be related to that. I have a 480gb ssd and a 1tb hdd. I will leave gparted`s view of them below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: “ I opened gparted and it shows errors with a lot of partitions, so I think it may be related to that.” ⇢ if you only have Windows 11 installed, then you shouldn’t have “a lot of partitions”. Can you [edit] your question to include your partition data, as well as any specific errors you may be receiving? Did you verify the ISO file you downloaded before making a bootable USB? 

Comment: Just did. Thank you